# JavaScript: show a message while a file is PREPARED for download (not while DOWNLOADING)

Tags: javascript, blazor-webassembly

I have a page where I use a form to initiate a file download. This is part of a Blazor WebAssembly project.
This tecnique is used to pass some parameters to the API that generates the file to download.

This is the JS function I use to start the download:

```
function downloadFromPost(options) {

    var form = document.createElement("form");

    form.setAttribute("id", "frm-download");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("style", "display: none;");
    form.setAttribute("action", options.url);
    
    var token = window.localStorage.getItem("authToken");

    if (token != null) {
        addHiddenField(form, "jwt", token);
    }

    delete options.url;

    for (const property in options) {
        addHiddenField(form, property, options[property]);
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
    form.remove();

}

function addHiddenField(form, name, value) {
    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", name);
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", value);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
}
```

For those interested, this is called by a Blazor page, this way:

```
<button type="button" @onclick="Download">Download</button>

@code {

    [Inject] IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    private async Task Download()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("downloadFromPost", new { url = "api/mycontroller/download", param1, param2);
    }    
}
```

When the form is submitted it takes a while for the API function to extract data and start streaming the file.

During this time, Chrome shows the classic spinning wheel.

[image]

When actual download starts, the spinning wheel is replaced by the site icon and download progress is shown in the download bar.

I would like to show a "wait..." message on the page *while download is being prepared*, i.e. when Chrome shows its spinning wheel.

When actual download starts I don't need it anymore, since download has its own progress indicator.

Is there a way to do this using JS/Ajax/jQuery?

I found other answers on this, but they involve using Ajax to buffer the file and write it to disk. I don't want this because this approach consumes client memory and takes care of the whole download procedure, while, as I already said, I'm interested only in the preparation step.

Thanks